# How to display String created in textArea to maintain formatting in Grails?

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm wondering what's the proper way to display a String, created by user using textArea input field?
When using fieldValue everything is in single line :/

Thanks,
Krystian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must place the variable you get from the database into a "pre" tag

```
<pre>${variable}</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to convert characters to HTML.  For example, new line characters (\n) would need to be converted to <br/>, etc.

You could also provide a RTE instead of the TextArea which generally give you HTML instead of plain text via JavaScript.  [Google Search Results](https://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=html%20rich%20t&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=html%20rich%20text%20editor).

Comment: Huh... one would think that by the time of 2.1 this would be done in a different way ;) Oh well.

Comment: Have to agree with @Krystian, I was hoping for a better answer as well, given all the nifty stuff that is in Grails.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with grails textArea property

```
<g:textArea escapeHtml="true" />
```

But it didn't work, so I found there's a property in textArea fields (html and gsp) that you should use when creating.
It's:

```
<g:textArea wrap="hard" rows="5" cols="20" />
```

That did the trick for me, and now everytime I call that field, from everywhere (textArea, textField, td, etc) it creates all the corresponding lines.

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/textarea